# Testing earring

Tags: manual-testing, test-design, quality-assurance

Here is my check list for testing earring.

**Manual testing**
Verify that   skin will discolor (a black or green color) 
if the gold isn’t real. 
Genuine gold will not react with the skin.

**Automated**

Test the gold clamp using electronic gold tester.

**Proactive**

Verify that the gold clamp will be made meets EU nickel free standards

**Reactive**

Verify that the gold clamp does not create allergic reaction to nickel

**Validation**

Verify that this clamp is gold, round and clamped for easy use

**Verification**

Verify that this earring is easy to put on your ears

**Positive**

Verify that the earring can put on your ears

**Negative**

Verify that the earring can’t put on your nose

**Component**

Verify that a diamond is real. Carefully drop the loose stone into the glass. If the gemstone sinks, it’s a real diamond.

Verify that the clip should be clamped

**Integration**

Verify that a diamond and clip well connected

**System**

Verify that clamp with diamond is easy to use

**Acceptance**

Verify that earring looks good and is easy to use

**Non-functional**

Verify that diameter of earring must be 13mm

Verify that width of earring must be 4mm
[image]

---

But i don't know is he all right or not?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about testing SOFTWARE :)

Answer (score 2):

I'll start off by saying, unrelated to the gist of your question, that this type of question, "Test the item" ones, even for juniors without *any* previous QA experience, are the **stupidest, least useful and crappiest** kind of questions you can ask a candidate and I would **strongly** consider working for a company where the tech interviewer asks this question... even if it is only one question out of a whole bunch.
This type of question needs to die. Fast.

Having said that, between the super-informative title and the body of the questions, I don't really know what you're *actually* asking!

If you're asking about whether you got all the "correct" testing categories, well, I'm QA for 12 years and don't know half of them (`Reactive`, `Proactive`, `Component`?!?!) or have long forgotten what they mean (`Validate`, `Verify`) and I, nor any other QA, have any use for them on daily business, so can't help you there.

If you're asking whether you got the right type of test per category, then *absolutely NOT*!
By `automation` I don't mean I want you to test the gold content of the clasp using a robot. I mean `Have the robot open-and-close the clasp 10000 times in a row to test the clasp's longevity`.
`Automation` is about having the machine do the boring, mundane, easy to get wrong ("did I already flip the clasp 9990 times, or was it 9989?!") tasks for us.
Also a `negative` test for an earing would *not* be that it can't be worn as a nose-ring... you'd be surprised. A better negative test would be: "Try to perform an operation with the earring where it does *not* function as a piece of jewlery, like turn on the TV with it". `Negative` tests are about using the product in ways it wasn't ever meant to be used and verifying nothing bad happens due to the misuse.

But ultimately, what I **would** like to see is figuring out what the purpose of the earring was, it's inteded use cases and so forth, so what I **would** like you to submit, had I been a stupid interviewer actually still asking a "test an earring" kind of question was:

- What is the main usage of the earring: is it a children's toy? A teenager's "look-at-me" cry? A grown woman's accessory? The queen of England's gift from her sons to her coming birthday?

  - I can tell you that for two of these cases, which I'll leave it for you to figure out, I, as a QA, would not sign off on the product as production-ready!
  - What standards, if any, should the earring meet, in terms of safety, quality of materials, durability of clasp? Does it meet them?
  - Since we seem to already have a prototype, in the picture above, was it tested for ease of use on a target audience? What was the feedback? (It's always nice when you can "involve" your target audience, let them test your product for you, get their feedback... and if you can have all that for free, then it's even better!)

Actual question like the clasp's durability **on average** (what does this, `on average` tell you, by the way?), or if the earring weighs, **on average** between 5-10 grams are all **valid and important** question, that I definetly expect you to ask as a QA of the product, no doubt!

But what I really want you to be is a domain expert on the subject of earrings: know the standards that govern the industry, know what is the expectation of the target audience, anticipate what a clueless (or even right-out malicious) user might use the product for, other than its intended use and have a test for all those aspects.

And if you don't know yet, as I'm sure you're not an expert on diamond earrings just yet, I expect you to be both **able and willing** to educate **yourself** on the subject using whatever source of data you can find.

Yes, I know, I probably didn't answer **your** question (which I still don't really know what it was).
I told you, however, what you could do to not have to ask this kind of questions again.

And let me tell you again, no matter even if you're a rookie with no prior experience, think long and hard before taking an offer from a company whose technical lead is so unimaginative and clueless that he resorts to this kind of questions.

Comment: This is my homework. I am taking QC courses and have been given the task of testing an earring using Test approaches, Level and Types. By the way, such questions are asked at the interview (as you said) so I must be prepared for such questions. I wrote a Check-list for almost every Test approaches, levels and type. It's just homework to test earrings without requirements, etc.
And I just wanted to know if I tested correctly

Comment: @Yamis - You should have said that this was homework and you wanted to know if you were doing your QC course homework well. I agree with O.F. that this is a stupid interview/homework question, but sadly it's a question that still gets asked.

Comment: @Kate Paulk Can you explain why this question is stupid? After all, these people have been working in the QC for over 5 years. And they still ask that question. Why do they think this a good question?

Comment: If someone is testing _software_, their ability to come up with a list of tests for a random object in an interview has zero correlation with their ability to test software. Or to design tests for software. That requires some knowledge and understanding of the software, as well as the ability to recognize patterns, see gaps between what's designed, what's built, and what the customer would expect, recognize awkward UI... All of which manifest very differently in physical objects than they do in software.